# Symfony2 constraint post data dependencies

Tags: forms, symfony

Is it possible to set post data as a class constraint option, e.g.:

```
MyEntity
    properties:
        field:
            - MyConstraint: { someOption: someValue }
```

I'd like to popuate `MyConstraint::someOption` with a submitted value.

I know about class constraints/targets, however i'll lose reuseability with the constraint (as it's bound to a class).

Or should I create a 2nd constraint, e.g. a class constraint that delegates to a normal constraint.

Or would it be possible via events? (e.g. alter the YAML defined constraint on PRE_SET_DATA)

Roland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way via form events :)

For future reference, here's how I did it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // fields etc.

    $validator = $this->validator; // injected via DIC (service @validator)
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($validator) {
        $entity = $event->getForm()->getData(); // populated with post data due SUBMIT event
        $metadata = $validator->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entity); // constraint metadata (validation.yml)
        $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('property_field', new SomeConstraint(array(
            'someOption' => $entity->getSomeValue() // postdata... we have it :)
        )));
    });
}
```